# Strange behavior defining implies operator in F#

Tags: f#

I tried defining my own logical implies operator in F# as follows

```
let (-->) p q = (not p) || q
```

But when i actually try it out, it appears not to be implementing the short-circuit OR

```
> false --> ((2/0)=1);;
System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.at <StartupCode$FSI_0015>.$FSI_0015.main@()
Stopped due to error
>
```

It should not be evaluating the consequent yet it is

Can anyone see what's wrong here? I am running F# in VS 2012

Answer (score 10):

When you write `a --> b`, what is really going on is a call to a function called `-->` with 2 parameters, `a` and `b`. The *operator* syntax is just some syntax sugar.

Before calling a function, the runtime must evaluate all the arguments to that function. So, before calling `-->`, it first evaluates `false` and then `(2/0)=1`. When evaluating this last expression, it throws an exception. Your *implies* function never gets called!

In some other languages, such as Haskell, you have lazy evaluation. That is, the parameters to functions are evaluated only if they are actually accessed inside the function. You can simulate that by not passing a value, but passing a function that evaluates to that value, or a [**thunk**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk_%28functional_programming%29) as it is called.

Note that, to implement this kind of functionality in F# (thunks), the function has to be slightly modified: it has to *call* the thunk to get its value, just like the example given by John Palmer:

```
let --> p q = (not p) || q()
let thunk = (fun _ -> ((2/0)=1))
false --> thunk
```

Notice the function call `q()` in the definition of the *implies* operator. If you don't give it a thunk on the second argument, it will not work anymore!

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `lazy` to evaluate the second argument on demand:

```
let (-->) p (q: Lazy<bool>) = (not p) || q.Force()
```

and you can call it as:

```
false --> (lazy (2/0=1))
```

Answer (score 3):

The evaluation of the RHS must occur before it is passed to the function so the division by zero occurs very early so such a guard will not work.

You could instead pass a function like so

```
let --> p q = (not p) || q()

false --> (fun _ -> ((2/0)=1))
```

Answer (score 2):

F# has strict evaluation strategy. This means that arguments are evaluated before being passed to a function. Because of this, `2/0=1` is evaluated before it is passed to your `-->` function, so the short-circuiting of `||` doesn't affect the evaluation of `2/0=1`, because that is evaluated before `||`.

You need to convert your function (the `-->` operator) to take it's arguments by name instead of by value. Practically, this means to make it take either `() -> 'T` or `Lazy<'T>`:

```
let (-->) p q = (not <| p()) || q()

> (fun () -> false) --> (fun () -> 2/0=1);;
true
```

OR, alternatively, using the built-in `lazy` construct. This way you can achieve the same results (provided your computations don't rely on side effects) with a bit more terse syntax:

```
let (-->) (p : Lazy<_>) (q : Lazy<_>) = (not <| p.Force()) || q.Force()

> lazy false --> lazy (2 / 0 = 1)
true
```

It's working, but it doesn't look too convenient. Unfortunately I think there's no simple way to get rid of `fun () -> ...`, but I think you can reduce the boilerplate a bit by defining some constants:

```
let True, False = (fun () -> true), (fun () -> false)
```

To further reduce the boilerplate of creating a lambda for every argument, you could try to use code quotations (and a library like [Unquote](https://code.google.com/p/unquote/) to evaluate them):

```
let (-->) p q = (not (eval p)) || (eval q)

<@ false @> --> <@ 2 / 0 = 1 @>
```

Comment: @MisterMetaphor--this has nothing to do with order of evaluation; it's got to do with eager vs. lazy evaluation which is orthogonal to order.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, you're right, I think I meant evaluation strategy. Thanks.